# can we include both a file type and text in a form in sending email using jsp

Tags: java, html, email, jsp

I'm developing an email program using JSP. In that I need to send data as well as upload file.

```
<form name="email" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/servlet/sendmail">
  <input type="file" name="namefile" size="40">
  <input type="text" size="100" name="sub">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

In servlet java program I can upload the file but the text fields returns null.

In doPost() method,

```
String msg=request.getParameter("sub");
```

Here `getParameter()` method returns null for text fields.

Can we include both file type and text in a single form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Can you please revisit my question...just now i've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible. You should obtain the text field using the same API as you've obtained the uploaded file. It's unclear which one you're using to obtain the uploaded file, so I can't give a detailed answer. But a defacto standard API to parse `multipart/form-data` requests is [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) and I've posted an answer before how to do that [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/upload-big-file-to-servlet/2424824#2424824). To the point, you need to handle cases as well where `FileItem#isFormField()` returns `true`. This indicates a "regular" form field.